Help Needed: Creating a Framed Abstract Page in LaTeX
I have a designated format for my master's thesis provided by my school. I would like to insert an abstract page, similar to the link below, right after the cover page in my thesis.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-pt4ZjEbVlOZMPzaKu_NpkEnQTWeXy3d/view?usp=sharing
The file was created using Microsoft Word, but I would like to replicate the same appearance in LaTeX. I'm sorry for the beginner-level question, but could you please advise me on the best commands to create this kind of frame? If you have any reference websites, I would appreciate it if you could share them.
===Additional===
Thank you for your response.
As a beginner, it seems like I will need to study more to keep up, but the quality is amazing.
However, it's a little different from the table format I attached as an example.
I also tried to reproduce it using a "tabularray", thinking it might work. However, I couldn't get the long text in the Abstract to wrap automatically, and it seems this method is also challenging. Is there any way to make long text in the table wrap automatically?
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
    colspec = {X[0.25,c,h] X[0.6,c,h]X[0.25,c,h] X[0.6,c,h] }, 
    cell{2-Z}{1} = {c=4}{},
    hline{3} = {0em},
    hline{5} = {0em},
    hline{7} = {0em},
    width = {\linewidth }
}
\SetRow{rowsep=5mm} Student ID & XXXX & Name  & Tomy Otsuka   \\
\SetCell{l} Title & & &   \\
\SetRow{valign=t, halign=l}\SetCell{l} aaa & & &   \\
\SetCell{l} Abstract & & &  \\
\SetRow{valign=t, halign=l}{Abstract This paper compares a sample of 124 independent high technology entrepreneurs with 112 corporate entrepreneurs (intrapreneurs) involved in developing and introducing high-tech innovations across Canada. The study investigates the general management and technical problems faced by these entrepreneurs and contrasts their approach to such issues as market research, financing and production. The approaches used by the two groups in analyzing their markets and in planning and financing of innovations are compared and contrasted. In general, the independent entrepreneurs were technically trained, usually possessing engineering training but no general management training or experience, neither themselves nor members of their management team. Corporate entrepreneurs were as likely to come from management backgrounds as technical, or else supported their lack of general}
&　& &    \\
\SetCell{l} Keyword & & &   \\
\SetRow{valign=t, halign=l} \SetCell{l} aaa & & &  \\
\end{tblr}


Try with tabular, post your code as a minimal working example if you need more help

Welcome. // Suggestion: stop mimicking MS-Word style as early as possible. More often than not it gives your document a less professional appearance.

Wrt your !Additional": Please provide the missing code lines so it will compile. Thank you

@MS-SPO yes, but note it is imposed by the institution. such styles invariably require bad typography to one extent or another, but you typically can't graduate without complying. so, as a general rule, yes. but sometimes that's what is needed. I was once asked to submit a review which looked as if it was done in word. pdf was fine. but I had to deliberately undo every nice thing tex does. there is even a philosophy package available which exists solely to force latex to produce output which looks terrible enough to satisfy such requirements.

Here is one way to do it.
It's most often a good idea to absorb complex details in macros. E.g. you would call your abstract page in the code below as
 \disabst{}{}{}{}{}

with the 5 parameters (to be entered)
% ~~~ parameters: 1: ID, 2: name, 3: Title, 4: abstract, 5: keywords

The macro itself does ordinary typesetting, where \vfill pushes the two parts (before and after it) apart as much as it can, and the % at each macros end of line avoids spurious blanks during expansion you don't want:
\newcommand\disabst[5]{%
    % ~~~ parameters: 1: ID, 2: name, 3: Title, 4: abstract, 5: keywords
    {\parindent0pt%
     \begin{center}%
            {\large{SUMMARY OF MASTER'S DISSERTATION}}%
     \end{center}%
    %
     \beg \textbf{Student-ID}: #1 \hspace{3cm} \textbf{Name}: #2%
     \beg Title\par\bigskip#3%
     \beg Abstract\par\bigskip#4%
     \vfill%
     \beg Keywords\par\medskip#5%
}}

Macro \beg is just a shortcut for repeatative things.
If you have no introduction to Latex, this online book may help you along: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for some blindtext

% ~~~ shortcut for the text fields ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\beg[0]{\bigskip\hrule\bigskip}

% ~~~ using a macro to absorb details, simplifying its use ~~~~
\newcommand\disabst[5]{%
    {\parindent0pt%
     \begin{center}%
            {\large{SUMMARY OF MASTER'S DISSERTATION}}%
     \end{center}%
    %
     \beg \textbf{Student-ID}: #1 \hspace{3cm} \textbf{Name}: #2%
     \beg Title\par\bigskip#3%
     \beg Abstract\par\bigskip#4%
     \vfill%
     \beg Keywords\par\medskip#5%
}}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 % ~~~ your abstract page ~~~~~~~~~
 \disabst{0123-456}
         {Shady, Slim}
         {My dissertations title}
         {Some abstract: \lipsum[5]
    
            \lipsum[7]
            
            And some more abstract abstract thingie.         
         }
         {keyword 1, key2, key3}
 \newpage
 
 \section{And so it begins}
    \lipsum[1-3] 
 
\end{document}


Thank you for your response. It looks amazing!
However, it's a little different from the table format I attached as an example, so I'd like to make some adjustments there. I also tried to recreate it using "tabularray" and "tabular," but I couldn't get it to work.
I've added the code to my question, and I would appreciate it if you could provide some guidance.

Here is an approach using Tikz, i.e. kind of "drawing" the page.
Though the layout can be done with tables, i.e. with multicolumns, the challange seems to be to guarantee vertical placement of the keyword line: Latex is a kind of "write-and-forgetAboutTheLayout" approach and no frame-based DTP (DeskTop Publishing).
Using the picture environement might work, too. Putting an \fbox{} around my previous solution might work too, after some adaptations. Using package xcoffins might succeed, too.  However, Tikz seems to give most freedom and flexibility in positioning elements on a page.
For Tikz novices
It's highly recommended to look up statements in the Tikz manual in parallel. It also won't hurt to read and try its tutorials sections several times. Basically you put a number of paths, which is a different word for performing actions, like drawing a line.
Structure of the code below

put the headline (normal Latex code)
draw that fancy grid (e.g. in a gray color) (Tikz from here on)
use \nodes to position and display text (constant and variable)
via macro \disabst{}{}{}{}{}

Let's preview the outcome with:

an empty abstract page (important check)
filled with content
some thesis text (blindtext)


Adjustments
This design remains somewhat complex in coordinate terms. I abstracted a few places as constants or styles (most are marked in the comment). Let's have a look.

Top line: While drawing the frame, I remember some positions (A0) .. (A3) to which the text and content will be related to position some nodes. Though some calculations could be automized or abstracted into a set of constants, somehow here is a trade-off point between legibility and result. In this approach I move the nodes centers to where they (probably) should be related to the drawn frame.
    % ~~~ positioning the content ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[align=center,xshift=1.75cm,yshift=-.75cm] 
                                        at (A0) {Student\\Identification\\Number};
    \node[xshift=1.50cm,yshift=-.75cm]  at (A1) {#1};
    \node[xshift=1.35cm,yshift=-.75cm]  at (A2) {Name};
    \node[xshift=2.90cm,yshift=-.75cm]  at (A3) {#2};

Title and Keyword lines show a simple approach: Just move the content a little to the right and display it. If you like that, just adjust the 10mm as needed. For even more unifority you may want to put tables there with the same first column width.
    \node [topic]       at (B) {Title\hspace{10mm} #3};
...
    \node [topic]       at (D) {Keywords\hspace{10mm} #5};

The Abstract "box" shows a different way to do it:

put "Abstract" with style topic with the shifts defined there
remember its position as (ABS)
relate the abstracts content to (ABS)
put a \parbox inside (where you may want to adjust its width)

    \node [topic] (ABS) at (C) {Abstract};
    \node [topic]       at (ABS.south west) {\parbox{14cm}{#4}};

Because the shifts defined in topic are applied twice, you may want to overwrite it. i.e. insert an other self-defined style.

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newcommand\disabst[5]{
 % ~~~ parameters: 1: ID, 2: name, 3: Title, 4: abstract, 5: keywords
 {\parindent0pt%
     \begin{center}%
            {\large{SUMMARY OF MASTER'S DISSERTATION}}%
     \end{center}
 }
 \vspace{3mm}%          << if you want to shift the frame a little down or up (-3mm)
{\parindent-10mm%       << shifts the whoöe thing to the left AND localized {}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 [
    frm/.style={gray},  % << frames color
    topic/.style={anchor=north west,xshift=6pt,yshift=-6pt},    % << adjust shifts
 ]
    % ~~~ drawing all those frames ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \def\mywidth{15}    % << if you want to adjust
    \def\myheight{1.5}  % << if you want to adjust
    \draw[frm] (0, 0  )       coordinate (A0) rectangle (\mywidth,-19.7);
    \draw[frm] (0,-\myheight) coordinate (B) -- +(\mywidth,0);
    \draw[frm] (0,-3.5)       coordinate (C) -- +(\mywidth,0);
    \draw[frm] (0,-18 )       coordinate (D) -- +(\mywidth,0);
    % ~~~ vertical lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \x [count=\i] in {3.5, 6.5 ,9.2}
        \draw[frm] (\x,0) coordinate (A\i) -- +(0,-\myheight); % (A1), (A2), (A3)
    
    % ~~~ positioning the content ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[align=center,xshift=1.75cm,yshift=-.75cm] 
                                        at (A0) {Student\\Identification\\Number};
    \node[xshift=1.50cm,yshift=-.75cm]  at (A1) {#1};
    \node[xshift=1.35cm,yshift=-.75cm]  at (A2) {Name};
    \node[xshift=2.90cm,yshift=-.75cm]  at (A3) {#2};
    \node [topic]       at (B) {Title\hspace{10mm} #3};
    \node [topic] (ABS) at (C) {Abstract};
    \node [topic]       at (ABS.south west) {\parbox{14cm}{#4}};
    \node [topic]       at (D) {Keywords\hspace{10mm} #5};
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
}}
                                
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \disabst{}{}{}{}{}
 \newpage
 
 \disabst{0123-456}{Shady, Slim}{My title}{Some abstract: \lipsum[5]\par Let me see:\par\lipsum[7]}{keyword 1, key2, key3}
 
 \newpage
 \section{Let the thesis begin}
 \lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}

